# Why does reassigning work rather than just returning in concat?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-concatenation

Just trying to figure out why reassigning works as opposed to just returning. I know there are probably better ways of doing this but I just want to understand.

Given: `const anArray = [1, 'foo', 2, 'bar']`

```js
 const getConcatenatedStr = (arr) => {
      let result = ''
      if (arr && arr.length > 1) {
         arr.forEach(() => {
            return result.concat('', ' ')
         })
       } else {
         result = ''
      }
      return result.trim()
   }
```

`console.log('result one:', getConcatenatedStr(anArray))` *returns* 'result one: '

```js
 const getConcatenatedStrReassign = (arr) => {
      let result = ''
      if (arr && arr.length > 1) {
         arr.forEach(() => {
            result = result.concat('', ' ')
            return result
         })
       } else {
         result = ''
      }
      return result.trim()
   }
```

`console.log('result two: ', getConcatenatedStrReassign(anArray))` *returns* `result two:`

Of course, this works as well, equal to `getConcatenatedStrReassign`:

```js
    // ...
      if (arr && arr.length > 1) {
            return result = result.concat('', ' ')
         })
    // ...
```

Comment: Do i get cancer or im just seeing emojis?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` takes a callback as an argument and performs that callback on each index of an array and returns `undefined`. So when your callback in the first example returns `result.concat()` you're really just returning `undefined` and not ever concatenating. That's why the second example works, you're actually reassigning `result`. The return in the second example is still superfluous because all it does is return `undefined`. Check out the docs for [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for a little more of an explanation here.

Comment: Thanks. That "superfluous" return was throwing me off. I needed to understand what you said: that `forEach` returns undefined. This and the comment from @Gabriele that `Array.concat` doesn't modify the source array helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not need to return anything from `forEach`
2. [`String.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) does not modify the source string.

So you need to re-assign if you want to keep adding to it.

Or you could do

```js
const anArray = [1, 'foo', 2, 'bar']
const cools = anArray.map(() => '').join(' ') || '';

console.log(cools);
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about mutability and how `String.concat` works. Yep. [Second sentence in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat). And nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` in `forEach` just return you from `forEach`, not from function